# Providing read only permissions on a document library and edit permissions on a list

Tags: permissions

Trying to give a group access to read document libraries but add/edit lists.  Tried creating a custom permissions level for this but would only allow one or the other.  How can I make this work?

Comment: I guess you want to give them access to read documents and add/edit list items ?

Answer (score 1):

Break List inheritance, make 2 custom permissions level, one for Item level permissions and one for list level. For item level add read permissions only but for List level select add/edit permissions.

add users to both groups or however you want it :)

more information on event handlers can be found by this link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx